# Python: Cannot write out floats in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

This is the code that I am running:

```
for x in range(0,90):
   print (x*(5/90))
```

for some reason, all it prints out are 0's. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that it is figuring that you really want Integers.  Try change it to be:

```
print(x*(5.0/90))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, worked as it is supposed to!

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```py
for x in range(0,90):
    print (5.* x/90))
```

Answer (score 0):

in python dividing an int by another int give an int so to get the float result you can simply add a ".0" behind any integer to avoid casting.

change it by

```
           for x in range(0,90): print (x*(5/90.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for x in range(0,90): print (x*(5/90.0))
```

Python is interpreting the numbers as integers and therefore the result is 0